# My 3D object does not move although having an armature

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature

I just started in the Blender world and I have created a 3D model with MagicaVoxel and I have bounded it to an armature as shown on the following image:

[image]

After binding the armature with the model my problem is that when I move a bone on pose mode the part of the model that must move does not move all together but lengthens like a bubble gum as the following image shows:

[image]

What I want to accomplish is that the entire "arm" moves when I move the bone that corresponds to the arm.

I hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: You have parented with the With Automatic Weight mode, which is not the right way to parent for machines/mechanic/robots... instead, parent With Empty Groups, then, in the Properties panel > Vertex Groups, you'll see that some vertex groups have been created that have the same name as the bones. Now, go in Edit mode and assign each part of the object to the vertex group this part is supposed to be part of

Comment: @moonboots How can I assign the bones with the part of the object?. I think my object is only formed by one part because I can't select only a part of the object in Object Mode

Comment: you need to go in Edit mode, select the arm for example, the in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, select the group the arm is supposed to be part of, and click on the Assign button

Comment: @moonboots Solved! Thank you very much for your help!